# moderncv-style giving error messages

Tags: moderncv

I have the following MWE using `moderncv`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{black} 

\name{Horse}{Horsey}
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2013--2016}{Ate grass on a field}{}{}{}{}
\end{document}
```

However, when I use `fancy` instead of `casual`, I get an error message of undefined control sequence. `fancy` is supposed to be part of the package though.

Comment: It says it can't find moderncvstylefancy.sty -- I found the sty-file online and placed it in the folder, but then I got the error ` undefined control sequence: \moderncvhead`

Comment: I updated my tex-distribution, it gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As result of our chat we found that the used version of `moderncv` is `1.5.1`.  That's the reason for the received error message

```
! LaTeX Error: File moderncvstylefancy.sty not found.
```

So an update of `moderncv` to the current version `2.0.0` is needed.

Sorry, I do not know how you have to do that with TeXLive on debian.

Answer (score 1):

To update your latex distribution on debian, i guess you should run

```
sudo tlmgr update --self
```

and then

```
sudo tlmgr update --all
```

Comment: It says no updates available

Comment: Do you use texlive from debian repositories or from the tug.org homepage? Repositories do not always provide latest versions of packages. So you might have to install it manually.

Comment: I just opened a console and pasted in your commands. I'm not too experienced with these things. How do I install a package manually?

Comment: Please have a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages